# Join Query issue - codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 2 tables `tb_user_group` and `tb_user_follow_group` i want to join this table in my style

`tb_user_group`

[image]

`tb_user_follow_group`

[image: Group Follow Image]

i want all records from `tb_user_follow_group` where `tb_user_follow_group.group_id` match with `tb_user_group.id` and `is_follow='accept'` also include `tb_user_group.id = 1` and get all the fields of this two table.

not necessary answer in CodeIgniter Syntax post simple query also

This is my try query

```
$this->db->select('tb_user_follow_group.*,tb_user_group.*');
$this->db->from('tb_user_group');
$this->db->join('tb_user_follow_group', 'tb_user_group.id = tb_user_follow_group.group_id', 'left inner'); 
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: do you show your try query?

Comment: from which table you want data and plz show your query..

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam i update my question check this

Comment: $sql = "select ufg.* from tb_user_follow_group ufg LEFT JOIN tb_user_group ug ON ug.group_id = ufg.group_id WHERE ufg.is_follow='accept' and ug.id = 1";

Comment: i want all data from `tb_user_group` but my joining table also included @Jenish

Comment: i show nothing result from this query @ShafiqulIslam

Comment: left inner to inner only and check the output

Comment: i try this @rahul_m but it display same 2 records

Comment: select *  from  tb_user_group left join on tb_user_group.user_id  = tb_user_follow_group.user_id where tb_user_group.user_id = $user_id

Comment: show error @Jenish it's in logically query

Comment: yeah it raw query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this but not tested

```
  select ug.* from tb_user_group ug LEFT JOIN tb_user_follow_group ufg ON ug.id = ufg.group_id WHERE ufg.is_follow='accept' OR ug.user_id='".$user_id."' GROUP BY ug.id;
```

Comment: i think it is right but only get `tb_user_follow_group ` records i want also `tb_user_group` table records

Comment: i will try to help you

Comment: you want to get only data which accept and id =1 then need and condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141884/discussion-between-imbs-and-shafiqul-islam).